# Is it possible to create editable organization chart using google visualization chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, google-visualization

I am using google visualization chart because it provide HTML5 rendering .

MY requirement is that I want to edit and delete nodes of organization chart . I have gone through google organization chart documentation chart but I didn't find any specific solution .

First I just want to know is it possible to edit nodes of organization chart in google visualization chart if yes how if No what is the alternative .

Thanks in advance

Comment: it's possible but you will need to provide some of the functionality -- listen for 'select' event on node, if selected present text box, when edit complete, use selection to update node data, redraw chart -- or delete node from data based on selection, redraw chart, etc...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thanks a lot